# how can put an imageview in Linearlayout in front of another imageview in total relativelayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i have one relativelayout that it contains some linear layout .before starting game ,we want that an image view with counter showing for some minute  and after some minute it become invisible.i want that when  images are back of temporal image ,backimage become  trasparent..i put an image over all that it's color is transparent .but a temporal image become transparen too.how can i fix it ?.
thank for your attention.

```
here is  my xml code


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundgame"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.nooshindroid.yastashir.MainActivity"

>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundgame"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rotation="-180"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bord1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="بردی"
            android:textColor="#00e676"
            android:textSize="120dp"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bakht1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="باختی"
            android:textColor="#ff1744"
            android:textSize="120dp"
            android:visibility="gone"




            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/equal1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="مساوی"
            android:textColor="#ebeff2"
            android:textSize="120dp"
            android:visibility="gone"



            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroundgame"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="radioButtonClicked"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="radioButtonClicked"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroundgame"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="radioButtonClicked"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="radioButtonClicked"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dip" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:visibility="visible"
            >

            <ImageButton

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/counter_back"
                android:id="@+id/image3"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="200dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/winner1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:rotation="-180"
                    android:text="شما برنده شده اید!"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20dip"
                    android:visibility="invisible"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/equation1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:rotation="-180"
                    android:textColor="#757575"
                    android:textSize="30dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:rotation="-180"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:rotation="-180"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/refreash"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/refresh"
                    android:visibility="gone"

                    />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_timerview_time"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/equation2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#757575"
                    android:textSize="30dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/winner2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="شما برنده شده اید!"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20dip"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundgame"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bord2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="بردی"
            android:textColor="#00e676"
            android:textSize="120dp"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bakht2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="باختی"
            android:textColor="#ff1744"
            android:textSize="120dp"
            android:visibility="gone"




            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/equal2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="مساوی"
            android:textColor="#ebeff2"
            android:textSize="120dp"
            android:visibility="gone"



            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroundgame"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="radioButtonClicked"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="radioButtonClicked"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroundgame"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="radioButtonClicked"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/blank_button"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="radioButtonClicked"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30dip" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

here is the code that put image temporally

```
      layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    cover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                for( i=1 ; i<4 ; i++){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startcounter.setText(i+"");
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        nextStep();
                    }
                });


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

and in next step we do in this way

```
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: take a look at framelayout. It only focuses one child at a time

Comment: i want that framelayout became in front of every thing when it is visible and not be transparent.